# Can't consume GlassFish generated WSDL from .NET

Tags: wcf, web-services, glassfish

I am trying to add a web service reference to my C# application in Visual Studio. The web service is hosted on Sun's GlassFish server. Unfortunately Visual Studio produces the following warning when I try to add the service reference:

```
Custom tool warning: The following Policy Assertions were not Imported:
  XPath://wsdl:definitions/wsdl:binding[@name='SecurityWebServicePortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='RegisterUser']
  Assertions:
    <wsat:ATAlwaysCapability xmlns:wsat='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat'>..</wsat:ATAlwaysCapability>
```

Apparently it cannot understand policy assertions in the WSDL published by the GlassFish server. Here's an excerpt from the WSDL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://test/securityservice.wsdl"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    targetNamespace="http://test/securityservice.wsdl"
    name="SecurityService">

    <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsat="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat" wsu:Id="SecurityWebServicePortBinding_AuthenticateUser_WSAT_Policy">
        <wsat:ATAlwaysCapability />
        <wsat:ATAssertion xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy" wsp:Optional="true" ns1:Optional="true" />
    </wsp:Policy>

    <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsat="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat" wsu:Id="SecurityWebServicePortBinding_RegisterUser_WSAT_Policy">
        <wsat:ATAlwaysCapability />
        <wsat:ATAssertion xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy" wsp:Optional="true" ns2:Optional="true" />
    </wsp:Policy>

    ...

    <binding name="SecurityWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:SecurityWebService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
        <operation name="RegisterUser">
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SecurityWebServicePortBinding_RegisterUser_WSAT_Policy" />
            <soap:operation soapAction="RegisterUser" />
            <input>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SecurityWebServicePortBinding_RegisterUser_WSAT_Policy" />
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#SecurityWebServicePortBinding_RegisterUser_WSAT_Policy" />
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
            <fault name="UsernameExistsException">
                <soap:fault name="UsernameExistsException" use="literal" />
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    ...

</definitions>
```

If I remove all the policy elements from the WSDL, Visual Studio is able to consume the service without any problems (in fact earlier I used to write the WSDL by hand and never put the policy statements). So my questions are:

1. Why is GlassFish insisting on adding the policies? Is there any way to suppress them?
2. Why is Visual Studio not able to consume the WSDL with the policies?

Comment: How are you using the WSDL? "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Yes - "Add Service Reference" and pointing to the URL for the WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out why GlassFish is adding the ws-AT policies. My web service is being generated using an EJB (see below):

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class SecurityWebService {
    ...
}
```

Since the default transaction attribute for a stateless EJB method is REQUIRED, GlassFish is making the web service method transactional too (see [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/WSIT-649) for details). Not the behavior I want, but that's how it is!

Answer (score 0):

ws-AT (Atomic Transactions) seems to be part of the SOAP specification which WCF does not know about.
There is some information here - http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat/

Update: Actually WCF is aware of the ws-AT spec, but doesn't support it fully (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat/).  I suppose this is because WCF has alternatives which use OleTransactions.

Comment: Could you provide a link that states this?

Comment: Thanks. Now that we know that ws-AT is causing the problem, is there any way to stop GlassFish from emitting ws-AT policies?